# A basic Qs about "token" at the creation complete function

Tags: apache-flex

I notice that every time I create something in flex and a function like

```
        protected function list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllProductstatusResult.token = productstatusService.getAllProductstatus();
        }
```

will occur in my script.

I know the "productstatusService.getAllProductstatus();" part is used to get the results, but what is the "getAllProductstatusResult.token" part doing? and what it is used for? and why it is linked to a call responer? and what is token means? (Very basic problem but bug me for a long time)

Comment: So you wrote this code, but you don't know what it's for? Strikes me as an odd programming methodology. Anyways try googling ASyncToken. You'll get plenty of information: http://www.google.com/search?q=flex+synctoken

Comment: What will occur in your script?  An error?  Or something else?

Comment: NOP, All the code is generated by Flex. I just cannot understand what "getAllProductstatusResult.token" is doing in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have provided us very little details, but...

```
I know the "productstatusService.getAllProductstatus();" part is used to get the results, but what is the "getAllProductstatusResult.token" part doing?
```

This is called variable assignment.  So, the results of the `getAllProductstatus()` of method call on the object instance `productstatusService` are saved to the instance variable  `token` on the `getAllProductstatusResult` object.

```
and what it is used for?
```

It is impossible to determine based on the code you've provided.

```
and why it is linked to a call responer?
```

Based on the code you've provided, there is no way to determine if a Responder is being used.  Assuming that a Responder from the method call and saved in the token variable, you'll have to perform a search in your code base to find out where that token is being used.

```
and what is token means?
```

It is an instance variable on the getAllProductstatusResult object.  Instance variables can be created like this:

```
public var token : Object;
```

or sometimes instance variables can be created using get and set methods to represent the property.

Comment: Token me some time to understand ^.^. The "token" is a variable that store all the value retrieve form the DataService and that is why the Flex generate so many .token in my script.  Nice and kick ass answer.